# Synonym [phraseology] -> [terminology]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are currently 2 tags with the same meaning, with approximately 20 questions in each: [phraseology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phraseology) and [terminology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

Can these be merged into [terminology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and a synonym added from [phraseology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phraseology)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [phraseology](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phraseology) and [terminology](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology) are not quite the same thing. Phraseology is how sets of words, assembled, mean something specific, while terminology is more about individual words.

Terminology is words like "ramp" or "tarmac", and concepts like "base leg" or "instrument conditions". Standard phrases like "climb and maintain", "land and hold short", or "cleared for approach" would be phraseology. Phraseology is in fact a [specific, standard aviation term](http://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/libview_normal.aspx?id=17272).

In fact, while they could use a little improvement, the existing tag definitions align with this:

> ## [terminology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
>
> Use this tag for any questions about specific words, phrases or definitions in aviation. If possible, add other tags to indicate the general subject area.
>
> If you have a question about terminology used in radio transmissions then you should usually use the [phraseology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phraseology) or [radio-communications](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communications) tags instead, but using [terminology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is still fine if you aren't sure.

...vs...

> ## [phraseology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phraseology)
>
> In aviation, standard radio (formally, radiotelephony) phraseology is used to ensure pilots worldwide are able to communicate in a unambiguous manner with Air Traffic Control.
> [...] Use this tag for questions about words, phrases and abbreviations used in aviation radio communications. More general questions about words, phrases or definitions should usually be tagged [terminology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) instead.

Maybe I'm overdoing it, but I feel like that is an accurate breakdown, and perhaps we simply need to be more explicit in the summaries. I'm in favor of leaving them as is.

Comment: Seems a bit verbose for me, but the community has spoken I guess.

Comment: It's not verbose, it's precise. There's a difference. :)

Comment: @DannyBeckett Put it this way.  Phraseology has a very specific meaning.  Terminology has a very specific meaning.  The two meanings are not the same, therefore they are not synonyms.